# Google Maps iOS rightCalloutAccessoryView replacement?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Just wondering what's the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` (the blue button below) replacement in the Google Maps SDK? Or do I need to make a custom view.....

[image: Apple maps callout]

**EDIT:**

Is there a better option than `GMSMapViewDelegate`'s:

`- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
    didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(id<GMSMarker>)marker;`?

(it isn't obvious to the user that you can tap the info window...)

**EDIT 2**

This *Plane Finder - Live Flight Status Tracker* seems to use default callouts with the iOS SDK: http://bit.ly/PFinder. How do you do that?

[image: Plane Finder - Live Flight Status Tracker]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it! :)

See https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/GoogleMapsCalloutView for an example project :)

[image]