# How to apply animations to GMSMarker

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I’m changing my app by migrating iOS maps to google maps using Google Maps SDK for iOS V1.1.0 and I’m trying to animate the markers while adding/removing but I didn’t find any suggestions in the documentation related to this, Please suggest me how to perform the animations on GMSMarkers

Comment: Can you tell me which kind of animations you like to add? I think than I will be able to answer you how to do it.

Comment: To drop pins from top, to increase and decrease frame size of pin by giving animation durations, i did these types of animations on MKMapView

Comment: this [earlier post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414780/do-marker-animations-exist-on-googlemaps-sdk-for-ios) discusses the same question.

Comment: @smily : hi buddy same task is for me and still no soulution found for drop pin from top. if you have any idea then plz share with me.thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543095/bounce-animation-on-google-map-marker-in-ios-objective-c/41764821#41764821

The continouse scale aniamtion on  Google Marker

Answer (score 8):

In the [GMSMarker Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker), it says, for the `appearAnimation` property:

> Controls the animation used when this marker is placed on a `GMSMapView` (default `kGMSMarkerAnimationNone`, no animation).

Using [the Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/), a marker can be made like this:

```c
GMSMarker *startMarker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:@"NYC"];
startMarker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
startMarker.title = @"Start";
startMarker.snippet = @"My address";
startMarker.map = mapView;
```

Comment: i cant see animation when google map show and marker appear suddenly